# How can I clone a fieldset?

Tags: 8, webforms

I've been searching for this for a while, but most of the articles I have found are from YEARS ago, so I wanted to jump in here and see if any of you lovely people have an idea... :)

I am creating a webform for a customer that has a fieldset that needs to be applied to different sections within the form, but with all the same fields within that fieldset.

Is there a way to actually duplicate/clone a fieldset within a webform in Drupal 8?

I'm using:

- Drupal 8.9.1
- Webform Version: 8.x-5.19

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank You!
Nicole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export config, then you'll have the fieldset in the resulting webform's Yaml. Then simply copy the whole fieldset in the Yaml, paste it to somewhere else in the Yaml and rename the elements. Now import the config again and your elements will appear in the form.

Export, paste, rename, import. That's it.